# Need to change the H1 on woocommerce product archive page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting SEO errors back stating that I have no H1s on my woo commerce products archive page. I am wanting to know if there is a way I can edit the PHP on the archive-product.php so that I can have an H1 for those archive pages and what would I need to edit?

```
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>

</header>
```

Comment: It should be displaying those by default. Do you have something hooked into the `woocommerce_show_page_title` filter that's disabling those?

Comment: That is related to your theme `header.php` and woocommerce integration in it… This is a theming problem for sure… So you will not find anything related on woocommerce templates…

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I guess my next step would be to take this to the theme company support and see what they can do.